# Business Spanish (Mexican and Puerto Rican vs. Colombian)

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, hispanoamérica

In my job, we work with customers calling into various businesses. All of the Spanish speakers are located in the United States, and they are mostly Mexican and Puerto Rican. However, we have a vendor in both Barranquilla and Bogota Colombia. They are having trouble with certain words and slang that the customers use, which results in lower quality.

For example:

"Cuota" is being used as "quote", the people in Colombia are understanding it as "fee"

"Cuenta" is used as "account", the Colombians are understanding it as "bill" and "balance"

"Factura" is used as "bill", and people in Colombia are interpreting it as "balance" or an inquiry of how much they owe.

These are the main ones, and I am trying to come up with more examples so the people in Colombia won't be confused.

What are some examples of Mexican/Puerto Rican Business Spanish that is different from Colombian Spanish? Mainly having to do with electric bills, accounts, payments, and balance.

I myself don't speak Spanish, so this has been a difficult obstacle for me.

Comment: I am not an expert on business Spanish, still less what is used in Colombia but I think you will find that several of those are widely used with the meaning which you think is restricted to Colombia.

Answer (score 2):

From Mexico I can tell below:

"Cuota" means "fee"

"quote" we call it "cotización"

"Cuenta" is also used as "account"

"bill" we call it "recibo"

"balance" same as in english, "balance"

"Factura" means "Invoice"

Comment: As spanish, I understand the same that in Mexico, so I would assume that this is the meaning more widely accepted